# Win10 iso can't be booted by grub2

Tags: boot, windows, grub2, iso

I have read https://superuser.com/questions/1355604/boot-win10-from-an-iso-image-on-a-certain-partition-using-grub2, then do as NorbiPeti instruction. It can get me to see the Windows installer, but if I click Install now, an error saying that "a media driver your computer needs is missing...".

Is it possible to do what he say?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Windows Setup cannot read its files from an ISO file directly. You must extract the files to the filesystem on the drive. I recommend [rufus](http://rufus.ie/) to do so.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1360972/windows-10-iso-on-usb-stick-wont-boot?rq=1) refers to [this article](https://wycd.net/posts/2015-03-10-creating-a-bootable-windows-10-usb-drive-on-linux.html) for a Linux-only solution, but I have not tried it with recent versions of Windows.

Comment: I've had good experiences with WoeUSB for creating Windows install media on Linux: https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB

Comment: But what I try to do is to do it without USB/DVD, that's why I'm here.

Comment: @psychows You should mention that in your question. Where are the installation files located? On an internal hard-drive?

Comment: Yes, On an internal hard-drive

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded in installing Windows 10 and it's working. I have two copies of Windows iso contents placing in NTFS partitions A and B, follow NorbiPeti instruction, choose /efi/boot/bootx64.efi in B as chainloader, boot to the Windows Installer, don't try to install now, switch to command line and run setup.exe from A:\source.

Comment: My fault, installing Windows 10 in this way will get other NTFS partitions disappeared, but can be seen in Live Ubuntu and data is fine. But I still need to access partitions in Windows 10, What's wrong and how to fix the wrong?

Comment: After converting the disk table to GPT, changing the partition type with `fdisk` to 11.